# Cannot set default theme. Dark theme even if loaded without .emacs and without .emacs.d

Tags: themes, default

When I load emacs without any configuration I see a dark theme: 
[image]

There is no way for me to get back to the default theme. I tried the following:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `disable-theme`: no theme is enabled
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-themes`: I can set custom themes, but disabling them gets me to the weird default dark theme
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `frame-background-mode`: setting to light/dark changes the colors slightly but no default emacs theme still, and I still have a dark background.
- starting Emacs without `.emacs` configuration : no change
- starting Emacs without `.emacs.d/` : no change
- removing completely Emacs with `apt remove --purge emacs*`, reinstalling and restarting it, without `~/.emacs`, without `~/.emacs.d/`: no change (??)

Are there configuration files/folders other than `~/.emacs` and `~/emacs.d/`?

**EDIT:** 
fixed using the help from this question: [Emacs cursor color is different in daemon and non-daemon modes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13291/emacs-cursor-color-is-different-in-daemon-and-non-daemon-modes)
It was indeed the Xresources. `xrdb -query -all` didn't give any "Emacs*" stuff but calling `xrdb -remove` fixed the issue !

Comment: Can you try running `emacs -Q`?

Comment: The issue persists with -Q
Edit : sorry, with -q the issue persists but with -Q, i get the default theme !

Comment: It might be your xresources https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9n5i4o/any_method_to_figure_out_what_theme_i_have_a_task/e7k6imp/?context=3

Comment: In that case, you have a site lisp file that sets a theme. The solution to your problem probably boils down to just removing it. It seems that `~/.Xresoucres` is ignored when you ignore the site lisp file, so you might want to look at it as well.

Comment: Same issue after deleting /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp. I dont have an ~/.Xresources file.