# How to change cursor color in emacs 27?

Tags: themes, cursor

Note that I'm using a theme (not sure if that changes things).

I have

```
(set-cursor-color "White")
```

But my cursor is still yellow.

Comment: Are you using Evil mode? Are you running Emacs in client/server mode? I'm asking because of this [thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13291/emacs-cursor-color-is-different-in-daemon-and-non-daemon-modes) and this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204316/cant-change-cursor-color-in-emacsclient/19321267#19321267)

Comment: Where do you do `(set-cursor-color "White")`? It may be that something changes the color *after* you do the above. If you type the above in your `*scratch*` buffer and press `C-j` after it, does the cursor color change?

Comment: Indeed running in *scratch* did change the color.  So my error was to have the set-cursor-color BEFORE setting the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Had to do the set-cursor-color after the custom-enabled-themes